# Android app Firebase user.getDisplayName() problem

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I've noticed a bug in my app when using user.getDisplayName().

If the account is saved on Google Smart Lock (but deleted from firebase) and the user signs up the function returns null (even though the picture and email show up just fine). However, if I select "none of the above" in the Smart Lock dialog and then sign up again using the google account method (the same that was saved in Smart Lock) the function returns the proper username.

Summarizing: if it is the first time the user signs up it should work, but if they delete the account and want to sign up again, Smart Lock is somehow preventing it from working. Any thoughts on how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone has the same problem: I didn't actually solve it, but a workaround is to use the FirebaseAuthUI to delete the account instead of the pure FirebaseAuth, because it also removes the account from SmartLock. As an alternative, you could also delete the account from SmartLock manually. As per the FirebaseUI documentation:

```
AuthUI.getInstance().delete(this).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                        // Deletion succeeded
                                    } else {
                                        // Deletion failed
                                    }
                                }
                            });
```